# Emacs: replace after rgrep?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I like `rgrep` a lot. The interface for finding and jumping between matches is great.

But I also want the ability to do interactive and non-interactive replacements
from the `*grep*` results window.

I mean the information for replacing is already laid out perfectly:

- the thing to be replaced is nicely highlighted
- some context is given (although it wouldn't hurt to bind
  <kbd>+</kbd> to increase the number of context lines)
- the files and positions are here as well

But there's no interface for replacement (I checked with <kbd>f1 m</kbd>).
Did I miss it or it's not available? Or is it available is some package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [wgrep](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/wgrep.el).  It uses `wdired` approach, and it is available in the usual package repositories.

Comment: The interface takes a bit to get used to, but it works. Thanks.